# JSTL Tags committing HTTP Response

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, httpresponse

I have a JSP that uses JSTL heavily (c:out, c:if, c:choose, the works). I am running into an interesting condition where during mid-for loop in the JSP my HTTP Response flips from being NOT committed to committed

The JSP has no reference to the response object at all, so I am not accidently flushing the response buffer.

I've set my response buffersize to be 1MB for testing (my page is 100KB) - in order to avoid automatic buffer flushing (and thus response commits).

The only thing I can think of is the JSTL tag libs (since they have access to the response object) is committing my response under the covers.

I cannot find any helpful docs online or the source code for the JSTLs to take a look myself.

Any thoughts?

Comment: A committed `ServletResponse` just means that it `has already had its status code and headers written`, see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#isCommitted()

Comment: Per API: reset() => Clears any data that exists in the buffer as well as the status code and headers. If the response has been committed, this method throws an IllegalStateException. basically Im stuck w that response (can't redirect, etc.).

Comment: You obviously can't redirect if you have already sent the status line and the headers.

Comment: Since you don't provide any code to analyse, we can't provide a proper answer either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was the JSP maintains its own buffer size which is uneffected by the response objects setBuffer(..).

```
<%@page buffer="256kb"%>
```